# How can I extract a Unique ID from a PDF file using C#?

Tags: c#, pdf

## How to read a specific part of a .pdf file using c# - Beginner

I'm trying to read a pdf file using c#, I am new to coding and I believe I a 80% of the way there.

I need to read this ID from the pdf called a unique id, it usually starts which a character followed by a series of numbers. Some of the pdfs are read without issue and the unique ID is found, however some throw an error like you see below, is there a cleaner very simple way to write this code? The code is a temporary solution so I don't need anything complex, I am pretty stuck on this one. the bolded section is where I am running into issues.

```
using System;

using System.IO;

using System.Text;

using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace NoticePDFProcessing

{

    class Program

    {

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {

            string dir = "C:\\split\\";

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir))

            {

                Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));

                string uid = ExtractUID(Path.GetFullPath(file));

                string bnum = Extractbnum(Path.GetFullPath(file));

                Console.WriteLine(uid);

                Console.WriteLine(bnum);

                System.IO.File.Move(Path.GetFullPath(file), "C:\\test\\" + uid + "-" + bnum + ".pdf");

            }

           

        }

        public static string ExtractUID(string path)

        {

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))

            {

                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)

                {

                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));

                }

              ** ** int startOrd = text.ToString().IndexOf("UNIQUE ID") + 11;

                int endOrd = 7;

                string roughUID = text.ToString(startOrd, endOrd);

                int newLineOrd = roughUID.IndexOf("\n");

                string fineUID = roughUID.Substring(0, newLineOrd);

                return fineUID;****

            }

        }

        public static string Extractbnum(string path)

        {

            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))

            {

                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)

                {

                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));

                }

                int startOrd = text.ToString().IndexOf("Card No") + 16;

                int endOrd = 5; 

                string roughbnum = text.ToString(startOrd, endOrd);

                string bnum = roughbnum.Trim();

                return bnum;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mb5Q.png)

[what i am trying to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWTb.png)

I keep getting this error, and the code fails to execute, I was hoping there was a simpler way to collect the Unique id

Comment: Hello friend, running in debug mode and/or adding some try catches and checking the exception stack trace will help you identify the line throwing the exception. That'll either help you fix it or make it easier for us to help. Running in debug mode will also show you the exact values of all the things when the error is thrown

Comment: Also the simpler way (not necessarily easier way) is through regex matching, I'll give it a quick go myself in a sec

Comment: One possible reason - when there is no newline in your `roughUID`, `newLineOrd` will be -1, so `roughUID.Substring(0, newLineOrd)` may fail with the exception you show. But you should definitively do as @TheLemon said, determine the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I gave it a quick stab based on my interpretation of your problem. Regex will make matching text a lot easier (that's what it's designed for). I'd also recommend ditching the stringbuilder - no point parsing pages after you found the one you were after.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    var pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i);
    var idMatch = Regex.Match(pageText, "UNIQUE ID.*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase); //match card no and 16 characters
    if (idMatch.Success)
    {
        var fullMatch = idMatch.Value;
        return fullMatch.Substring(11);
    }
}
```

The above looks for unique ID, returns unique id with the rest of the line, then returns everything after the 11th character.

A few tips with coding, try {code}catch(Exception ex){ //stuff} is your friend

Running in debug mode to check what values are actually being processed at each line helps, and sticking things into methods and checking said methods in isolation also is a huge help.